# How to get ringtone path in android

Tags: java, android, media, database-cursor, ringtone

Whether exists way to get direct path to some ringtone uri,which we can get via ringtoneManager,which will works for all apis. I need in direct file path to play it on media player without looping. Have anybody ideas,how to get absolute path of any ringtone? Thanks everybody for any help.

Comment: "how to get absolute path of any ringtone?" -- you do not have filesystem read access to any ringtone. There is also no requirement for the ringtone to be a file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue as well, And i found solution that i explain you how i get atual ringtone in `Android`.

**NOTE:** but you need those permission first.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```
Uri defaultRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Ringtone defaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), defaultRingtoneUri);
```

OR

You need to got all `default ringtones` in android `with path`. then you can use this code in android.

```
RingtoneManager ringtoneManager = new RingtoneManager(this);
ringtoneManager.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Cursor cursor = ringtoneManager.getCursor();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    Log.e("RINGTONE", "NAME: " + cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX));
    Log.e("RINGTONE", "PATH: " + cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.URI_COLUMN_INDEX));
}
```

Comment: urvish-shiroya I want to get list of all ringtones,and i want to get direct path to each ringtone,because i know it uri. How i can get it?

Comment: @Aleksandr Kozlovskiy 
I updated my answer, you can check if it works for you.